# React: Code not rendering on the website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning React and doing a starter project I thought of myself to help me learn. I am just doing a little webpage. I wrote the code and ran it, but it does not seem to render on the webpage. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class toDoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>My To Do List</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <toDoList/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: As in @MayankShukla's linked question, your class needs to start with a capital letter, so try calling it `class ToDoList`.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked now!